# Camel Apache & Activemq redeliver to original queue

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I have a route like this:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period="+TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))
            .process(exchange -> {

                System.out.println("Inserting: "+ new Date());

                exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "GET");
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("accept", "application/json");

            })
            .to("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .process(exchange -> { new TestProcess();})
            .to("activemq:jasonplaceholder");
from("activemq:jasonplaceholder")
            .transacted()
            .unmarshal(new ListJacksonDataFormat(Post.class))
            .process(exchange -> {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Post> posts = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                System.out.println(posts);

                posts.forEach(post -> {
                    iDaoPost.insertPost(post);
                });


            });
```

And a want to rollback my JSON message to the original queue if an error occurs.
Currently, my message is delivered to the DLQ of activemq, but i want to redeliver it to the source queue, when there's an error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in theory you can do it with an [ExceptionClause](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html) which is part of Camel's [error handling](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/error-handling-in-camel.html)

```
onException(ExceptionTypeYouWantToCatch.class)
    .to("activemq:jasonplaceholder");
```

However, I have no idea if it CAN work in a transactional consumer to **produce into the same queue as you consume from**. Simply because I never did this.

DLQs (dead letter queue) and DLTs (dead letter topic) are in place because erroneous messages block your whole processing if you don't move them out of your way.

Imagine what happens when a message cannot be unmarshalled (or has any other persistent error):

- error occurs
- message is moved back to the source queue
- message is consumed again (if there are no other messages, immediately)
- error occurs
- message is moved back to the source queue
- and so on

I guess you want to implement some kind of retry to handle temporary errors.

What I did for such cases was

- move erroneous messages to an error queue (not the DLQ)
- add another consumer that consumes the error queue
- when an error message is consumed, a message header with a retry count is incremented
- then the message is moved back to the source queue with a delay (for example 1h)
- if the same message is consumed multiple times from the error queue (for example 5 times), it is moved away to the DLQ
- messages in the DLQ have to be analyzed by a human